# Converting List to Dict from different length of list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I try to convert 2 lists of different sizes to get a dictionary

```
listA = [123,456]
listB = ['B123', 'B123', 'C456', 'C456']

Output 
DictA = {123:['B123', 'C123'], 456: ['B456', 'C456']}
----------------------------------------------
listA = [123,456,789]
listB = ['B123' , 'C123', 'B456', 'C456', 'B789', 'C789']

Output
DictA = {123:['B123', 'C123'], 456: ['B456', 'C456'],  789: ['B789', 'C789']}

#My attempt:

[ {a: [b,c]} for (a, b,c) in zip(product(listA ,listB ))]
```

that is the code trying but it shows me error

Comment: You need to be explicit about *why* these values go together. Is it because all but the first digit match? Is it always two values then the next two?  Also, please make sure you give valid python. We don't know if the values in `listB` represent variables or strings you, for some reason, didn't put in quotes.

Comment: the objective is that each value of list A must always go with 2 consecutive values of list B. The values of both lists are already ordered.

Comment: Have your tried `for x in zip(product(listA ,listB )): print(x)` to see it actually produces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` to get the in index of each key. You can use this to construct a slice from the list of values.

```
listA = [123,456]
listB = ['B123','B123','C456','C456']

{k:listB[2*i:2*i+2] for i, k in enumerate(listA)}

# {123: ['B123', 'B123'], 456: ['C456', 'C456']}
```

Alternatively, you can zip the list with an offset of itself skipping by two, then zip that with the keys:

```
pairs = map(list, zip(listB[::2], listB[1::2]))
dict(zip(listA, pairs))

# {123: ['B123', 'B123'], 456: ['C456', 'C456']}
```

If you are okay with tuples instead of lists, you can leave out the `map()`:

```
pairs = zip(listB[::2], listB[1::2])
dict(zip(listA, pairs))

# {123: ('B123', 'B123'), 456: ('C456', 'C456')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
DictA = {}
val = iter(listB)
for key in listA:
    DictA[key] = [next(val), next(val)]
```

which from your inputs gives:

```
{123: ['B123', 'B123'], 456: ['C456', 'C456']}

{123: ['B123', 'C123'], 456: ['B456', 'C456'], 789: ['B789', 'C789']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using a function with [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```py
def create_dict(listA, listB):
    DictA = {} 
    for i in range(0, len(listB), 2):
        DictA.setdefault(listA[i//2], []).append(listB[i])
        DictA.setdefault(listA[i//2], []).append(listB[i+1])
    return DictA

listA = [123,456]
listB = ['B123', 'B123', 'C456', 'C456']
  
print(create_dict(listA, listB))
```

---

```
{123: ['B123', 'B123'], 456: ['C456', 'C456']}
```

```
listA = [123,456,789]
listB = ['B123' , 'C123', 'B456', 'C456', 'B789', 'C789']

print(create_dict(listA, listB))
```

---

```
{123: ['B123', 'C123'], 456: ['B456', 'C456'], 789: ['B789', 'C789']}
```